# what is the size of Character(char) in Java?

Tags: java

What's the size of Character(char) variable in Java? if it is based on Unicode, what 's the unicode format it is use, UTF-8, or UTF-16?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character according to *[The Java Tutorials.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*

Answer (score 3):

[Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

P.S. Is this question worth asking? Just 5 seconds of google'ing...

Comment: My guess is that it seems the OP asking about the size of Character, not char (though it's not really clear). Though I believe those should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

A Java `char` is 16 bits, and holds a code unit for UTF-16–encoded Unicode code points.

Answer (score 0):

Character.MIN_VALUE is 0 and Character.MAX_VALUE is 65535.

Strings are UTF-16 encoded and can give you 16-bit unsigned `char` or code points of type `int`.